# Many errors from a simple CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

I'm trying to use QtCreator to compile and run a simple program with two source files and a header, that also uses the boost libraries. For compatibility with other code, I'm trying to use CMake but I seem to be failing miserably and no search result presents any meaningful help

My current CMakeLists.txt file is below. It's nothing close to a complex code or project, but I can't get it to do what I want.

```
project(Testing)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")

#####Boost
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options system)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

#####Threads
find_package(Threads)


set(INCLUDELIST TestHeader.h)

set(SOURCELIST main.cpp TestClass.cpp)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH, ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

message(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp ${INCLUDELIST} ${SOURCELIST})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})    
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

Problem number 1: This creates another folder outside the main Testing folder (which is the root of the project) called build-Testing-Desktop-Default, and dumps the executable in there.

P. N°2: No bin or lib folders are created anywhere

P. N°3: Executable doesn't do anything

P. N°4: Trying to run the executable through QtCreator (pressing the green 'play' button) just produces a "No executable specified." message as application output

I'm sorry this is such a low level question, I'm genuinely going mad here since apparently there are no useful search results/tutorials for any of this

Comment: Problem 1 seems like default behavior of Qt...

Comment: Oh. I see this is using CMake with QtCreator. I can't help with that.

Comment: `set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH, ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)` There is no comma in a set. Replace with `set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)` do similar for LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH

Comment: @DrewMcGowen does Qt force the executable to end up in an automatically generated folder then?

Comment: BTW its LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH not LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY. I checked that with `cmake --help-variable-list`

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks, that's problem number 2. I guess no libraries are being created so it doesn't create /lib, but now /bin shows up with the executable in there

Comment: The "No executable specified." error still haunts me

Comment: Try even more smaller example. Leave only one executable with main.cpp as source and see what happens. BTW do not forget to remove temporary build directory before cmake configure